# CSS3 not selector with last-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following css which needs to alter the last-child which does not have the class "myClass" but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
ul li:not(.myClass):last-child a {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

**Example html as requested:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li class="myClass"><a href="#">Extra</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply the css to li three...

Comment: Maybe give a short example of html code to match against and your desired result.

Comment: did you try to add pseudoclasses other way round? `ul li:last-child:not(.myClass) a` ?

Comment: @Mat tried that... still no joy though - is seems to be working on the theory that both last-child and not(.myClass) need to be true

Comment: oops, my bad... I'll edit now.

Comment: Yep, and for the sake of the example you should also insert a style definition that could be visible – unlike a zero pixel border. A similar setup: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/PDEwq/

Comment: @Tom: See my answer below, hope this help you.

Comment: There's no way to select the element preceding an element with a certain class. You need to rethink what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can't be done with css only if you are capable to use jQuery you might find this solution helpful.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ku3Y/

```
$('ul li').not('.myClass').last().find('a').addClass('mystyle');​
```

Comment: Was trying to avoid jquery where possible, but I think in this case it's going to be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the element you want to target is the last but one, you can use `nth-last-child(2)`

```
ul li:nth-last-child(2) a {
    border-right:0px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I can't always be sure it will be the last but one... sometimes ".myClass" won't exist... otherwise this would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the css only to li three, Try :nth-child(3)

```
ul li:nth-child(3) a​ {
    border-right:0
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhncn/

> This pseudo-class matches elements on the basis of their positions
>   within a parent element’s list of child elements.
>   – http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: Sure this would work, but the trouble is the number of list items won't be the same on every page and writing new css for each page really shouldn't be necessary - plus the ".myClass" element won't be present on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ul li:not(.myClass):nth-last-of-type(2) a {
    border-right:0px solid #000;
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kzNyk/)

Answer (score 0):

Current CSS syntax is not capable of facilating an `AND` operator to perform this kind of style. What you need is the [CSS LESS](http://lesscss.org/) Framework.

This will allow you to do this:

```
ul > li:not(.myClass) {
  li:last-child {
    //style here
    }
}
```